# How do I get a callback when user returns from settings activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, callback, gps, android-lifecycle

I spent a whole day on this, so hopefully someone answers it.

I have a location-based app, and I have a LauncherActivity which do some setup and then starts the MainActivity. The LauncerActivity ends with two important checks:

1. Checks for GPS permissions and asks for it if it doesn't exist.
2. Checks whether GPS is enabled right now and if not- asks the user to enable it.

Tese two checks are practically two dialogs. Now the problem is that after those two checks comes the line "startActivity(mainActivityIntent)". This doesn't allow the previous two checks to exist. I can't find the proper way to implement my needs. I know how to start the settings when user agrees to enable GPS, but I don't know how to recognize his return to my LauncherActivity so I can start the MainActivity.

I tried implementing some custom interface for getting callbacks from the "enable GPS" dialog when clicked, I tried manipulating this through the BackStack, but I just can't find a proper way.

I'm not sure I explained myself well enough and my english isn't that good anyway so I will happily give more details if you tell me to. I can also post some code to explain myself.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just check again onResume?

Comment: For permissions, you should be using `requestPermissions()` and `onRequestPermissionsResult()`. For enabled/disabled, there is no requirement that the user return to your activity. You could lead them to Settings, they could do stuff in there, then press HOME, or RECENTS, or click on a `Notification`, etc. If you are using the fused location provider in Play Services, use `SettingsApi` to request that the user enable GPS using a dialog. Otherwise, just respond to the appropriate method in your `LocationListener`, or check again in `onStart()`/`onResume()` as Ken suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onRequestPermissionsResult` method in your LauncherActivity like this:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String permissions[],@NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && grantResults.length > 0
            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

It checks if the result is successful. 
The REQUEST_CODE is a random int you send with `requestPemissions`.